# VueJS random number gets generated only once

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make a simple VueJS app with the ability to use multiple APIs, grab an image and display it to the user. This is my first try with Vue after watching some videos of a course, so please don't hate me if I dont use a VueJS function but use pure JS.

I want that the user clicks a button, then it will request an image from an API. What works is that it picks an api randomly, but for the Flickr API I need to specify a tag (which are saved in an array, picked randomly too). But it only picks the tag once and every time I call the function again it's the same tag! Means the function only gets executed once the page is reloaded.

Why is it like this and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

My code so far

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            // some data
            apis: [this.flickr(), this.desktopper()],
            wallpaper: '',
            wallpapers: [],
            screenWidth: window.screen.width,
            screenHeight: window.screen.height,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // The random function
        randomNumber(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        },
        // The main function, calls an api and should get the image source
        requestWallpaper() {
            var wallpaper = this.apis[ this.randomNumber(0, this.apis.length) ];
            console.log(wallpaper);
        },
        // Flickr API request random image
        flickr() {
            // Most popular tags of all time on Flickr (tags are needed to request images)...
            var popularTags = ['sunset','beach','water','sky','red','flower','nature','blue','night','white','tree','green','flowers','portrait','art','light','snow','dog','sun','clouds','cat','park','winter','landscape','street','summer','sea','city','trees','yellow','lake','christmas','people','bridge','family','bird','river','pink','house','car','food','bw','old','macro','music','new','moon','orange','garden','blackandwhite'];
            // Grab a random tag
            var tag = popularTags[ this.randomNumber(0, popularTags.length) ];
            return tag;
        },
        // Desktopper.co API request random image
        desktopper() {
            return 'desktoppr';
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img id="random" src="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button v-on:click="requestWallpaper">New Wallpaper</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML where you're calling the `requestWallpaper()` method.

Comment: Sorry for missing that! I've included the body part, in the head is only inline css for resetting the body and the unpkg cdn vue file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're `apis` array.

```
apis: [this.flickr(), this.desktopper()],
```

You're calling both the `flickr()` and `desktopper()` methods. That's what the parenthesis `()` means, they're so you can pass arguments to that method. Instead, you should exclude the parenthesis so that you're only storing a *reference* to each method.

```
apis: [this.flickr, this.desktopper],
```

Then, when you call `requestWallpaper()` you'll need to first get the random API, and *then* call it from its reference.

```
// get a reference to a random API
var api = this.apis[ this.randomNumber(0, this.apis.length) ];
// call that reference, with parenthesis and get the wallpaper result
var wallpaper = api()
```

Comment: Very nice explanation, thank you very much! Approved.